# c# Moving Socket to another Socket inside a different class?

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, sockets, transfer

I'm trying to build this server that receives connections on a socket, authenticates the user and then "sends" the socket to the class of the user that matches it(with the info given in the authentication), to be added to a thread pool (of the multiple devices of that client) in that same class to be processed (exchanging information, updating things elsewhere, etc..).

I need to move it to another Socket inside another class, then the threads open on that class will process it. If I accept the connection to authenticate it, that socket then is having that connection, beforehand I couldn't have known to accept it with the specific socket in the specific class because I didn't know where(who) it came from, and now, I have a thread I can't do anything with because I can't tell that class to use this thread, because if I do and use it in a thread of that class, the next socket I use to accept the connection will be the one that's occupied by that same class. I could use a huge array to store accepted sockets and tell classes that that socket number was theirs, but that would not only be limited but a bunch of loose sockets as well, which would work but would be neither optimized or organized.

So is anyone aware of any way to do this, or should I take a different approach? Thank you.

Comment: I'm confused about what you're writing, but usually you do this: Use a `TcpListener` and asynchronously accept clients. When a new client connects, spawn a new thread that handles the accepted client socket and start to wait asynchronously for more clients. The listening socket will not be blocked by this. A very simple example is found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I now understand my question was not at all needed, for anyone in my situation you may go read and understand [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx) example.

I've now learned that I should learn any and all documentation before posting on here, I had come by that example before and my laziness crippled me time-wise.

If you ever happen to be in a situation when you don't want to do something because of laziness, do it, it will reward you. Thanks to [Thorsten Dittmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/117362/thorsten-dittmar) for pointing me back there tho.

Have a nice day.